# What are the min rights I need to be able to script a table/view using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to produce the DDL for various objects in a db. What are the minimum rights that I need to be able to do this?

Comment: `VIEW DEFINITION` is the minimum level needed.

Comment: If you’re feeling brave you can consult [this monster of an info-graphic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/master/samples/features/security/permissions-posters/Microsoft_SQL_Server_2017_and_Azure_SQL_Database_permissions_infographic.pdf) ([source - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine)). I printed it on A3 once. Still a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not having the DBO role may prevent certain SSMS designer GUI interfaces (SQL Server version varying) from populating or opening without error (e.g. when modifying tables or columns through the GUI) even though doing it via T-SQL works and the permissions are in place. In some versions of SQL Server this may be resolved by allowing GRANT **VIEW DEFINITION** where this is an issue and it can also just be a warning only on certain versions of SQL Server.

Please refer the below links for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164237.aspx

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/467582/db-ddladmin-role-doesnt-allow-use-of-design-functions-in-ssms